# How to plot wind vectors on wind map

Tags: r, vector, raster

I have NAM wind models that I create map from but I am struggling to add average wind direction vectors. How do I convert the U and V vectors so they give average direction for a sub sample of wind angles? Currently when I plot wind direction the arrows are all swirling. Do I need to some how average wind direcions over chunks of area.

[map][1]

```
library(here)
library(tidyverse)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(lubridate)
library(ggquiver)
library(magick)
library(metR)
library(rCAT)
library(circular)
library(rNOMADS)

crop_ras <- raster(xmn = -121.404,
             xmx = -117.064,
             ymn = 32.36,
             ymx = 34.75)

date <- as_date(Sys.Date())

mod.list <- c("00", "03", "06", "09", "12", "15", "18", "21", "27", 
              "30", "33", "36", "39", "42", "45", "51", "54", "57", "60", 
              "63", "66", "69", "75", "78", "81", "84")

gribstring <- "wind_u_%s.grb"
wind.u <- vector("list", length(mod.list))

#U Vector
unlink(here("grib_u/*"))
for(i in seq_along(mod.list)) {
  url_ucomp <- paste0("https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_nam.pl?file=nam.t00z.awphys" , mod.list[[i]] , ".tm00.grib2&lev_10_m_above_ground=on&var_UGRD=on&subregion=&leftlon=0&rightlon=360&toplat=90&bottomlat=-90&dir=%2Fnam.20220512")
  gribfile <- sprintf(gribstring, mod.list[i])
  download.file(url_ucomp, here("grib_u", gribfile))
  
}

wind_u_brick <- stack(here("grib_u", list.files(path = here("grib_u"), pattern = "*.grb"))) %>% 
  projectRaster(crs = 4326) %>% 
  crop(crop_ras)

wind_u_csv <- rasterToPoints(wind_u_brick) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  pivot_longer(!c(x,y), names_to = "date", values_to = "u")


# V vector
unlink(here("grib_v/*"))
for(i in seq_along(mod.list)) {
  url_ucomp <- paste0("https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/filter_nam.pl?file=nam.t00z.awphys" , mod.list[[i]] , ".tm00.grib2&lev_10_m_above_ground=on&var_VGRD=on&subregion=&leftlon=0&rightlon=360&toplat=90&bottomlat=-90&dir=%2Fnam.20220512")
  gribfile <- sprintf(gribstring, mod.list[i])
  download.file(url_ucomp, here("grib_v", gribfile))
  
}

wind_v_brick <- stack(here("grib_v", list.files(path = here("grib_v"), pattern = "*.grb"))) %>% 
  projectRaster(crs = 4326) %>% 
  crop(crop_ras)
  

wind_v_csv <- rasterToPoints(wind_v_brick) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  pivot_longer(!c(x,y), names_to = "date", values_to = "v")

wind_data <- left_join(wind_u_csv, wind_v_csv, by = c("x", "y")) %>% 
  dplyr::select(!c("date.y")) %>% 
  rename(date = date.x)
  
wind_data$date <- str_replace(wind_data$date, "wind_u_", "")
  

wind_ras <- wind_data %>%
  mutate(wind = ((sqrt((u^2) + (v^2)))),
         angle = atan2(u/wind, v/wind),
         angle = (angle * 180/pi),
         date = as.factor(date)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-c(u, v)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(x, everything()) %>% 
  relocate(wind, .before = date) %>% 
  mutate(wind = wind*1.94)

wind_angle <- wind_ras %>%
  dplyr::select(c("x", "y", "angle", "date", "wind")) %>%
  group_by(x, y, date) %>%
  summarize(angle = mean(angle),
         wind = mean(wind),
         x =x,
         y=y,
         date = date) %>%
  mutate(angle = angle + 180)

wind_ras <- wind_ras %>% 
  dplyr::select(!c(angle))

date <-  unique(wind_ras$date)

ras <- brick(xmn = -121.4329,
             xmx = -117.1239,
             ymn = 32.3719,
             ymx = 34.7869,
             nrows = 23,
             ncol = 31)

for(i in 1:length(levels(wind_ras$date))) {

  ras[[i]] <- wind_ras %>% 
    filter(date == levels(date)[i]) %>% 
    rasterFromXYZ() %>% 
    dropLayer(2)
}

names(ras) <-  date

wind_pal <- colorRampPalette(c( "#7635b8", "#3a57ba", "#4999b3","#5bc752", "#c9b84d", "#cc8247", "#ab3c4d", "#bf4182" ))

wind_limits <- c(0,50)

wind_values <- c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50)

wind.list = lapply(sort(unique(wind_ras$date)), function(i) {
  ggplot(data = wind_ras[wind_ras$date==i,], aes(y=y, x=x)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = wind), interpolate = T) +
  facet_wrap(~date) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = wind_pal(100), limits = wind_limits, breaks = wind_values) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.line=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),
          axis.title.x=element_blank(),
          axis.title.y=element_blank(),
          panel.background=element_blank(),
        panel.border=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        plot.background=element_blank(),
        plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0), "null"),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_blank()) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-121.45, -117.06), ylim = c(32.36, 34.75), expand = F)
})


wind.arrows <- wind_angle %>%
  ungroup() %>%
    slice(which(row_number() %% 100 ==1))

test_wind <- wind.arrows %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(date == date[[2]]) %>%
  dplyr::select(!c("date"))

a <- wind.list[[2]]


a +
  geom_spoke(data = test_wind, aes( x = x, y = y, angle = angle,
           radius = scales::rescale(wind, c(.02, .15))), arrow = arrow(length = unit(.2, 'cm')))


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o60am.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD6d1.png
```

Comment: You could spatially average wind data on the source raster level, e.g. with `movingFun` of package {raster}: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.5-15/topics/movingFun

Comment: This might work. Do you think taking the average wind direction for given locations with say a buffer based on lat and long?

Comment: Not quite. As far as I understood, you begin with a raster from which you then pick the centroids and values per pixel (using `rasterToPoints`). My suggestion is to do the moving two-dimensional averaging right on the raster - a routine operation for which dedicated functions like `movingFun` exist and pick the averaged values. Achieving the same at the dataframe stage will probably get much more involved and slower. At the raster stage, you'll set the buffer (neighbouring pixel count) via the moving window's size.

Comment: That makes a lo of sense. I will give it a go. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of such a map, a think. This may not directly answer your question, but it shows how to provide some minimal example code. Your code is unnecessarily complex for the question at hand. Perhaps you can expand the code below a bit and use it in your question.

```
library(rasterVis)
library(raster)
proj <- CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84')
df <- expand.grid(x = seq(-2, 2, .01), y = seq(-2, 2, .01))
  
df$z <- with(df, (3*x^2 + y)*exp(-x^2-y^2))
r <- rasterFromXYZ(df, crs=proj)
vectorplot(r, par.settings=RdBuTheme())
```

But perhaps your question is really about combining U and V values? In that case, the code you would show would just create two vectors, one representing plausible U values, and one with plausible V value; and what you have tried to combine the values.

Comment: So I think vectorplot would get me to where I want but will give me further issues down the road in my code. Could you please elaborate on my attempt at the U and V values? Ideally I would like to have 50-60 arrows on the map that indicate average direction. However all the arrows are swirling in the random directions. I have updated the post with an image of the result

Comment: See my answer above about how to get started (by providing a minimal reproducible example)

Comment: If you copy and paste the code it will run smoothly. It is fully reproducible.

Comment: But I do not know where to look as it is much too long. It also involves downloading data (there should be no need for that), and requires many packages that I would need to install first (using `library(tidyverse)` is especially bad). I am not keen to spend much time on a question if you do not want to spend the time to properly ask it.

Comment: Ok I understand now. I need to cut out the extra steps in my code. I will work on that. Why is the tidyverse bad?

Comment: The tidyverse package depends on about 30 other packages that I would need to install. Also, the script would be much clearer if you just loaded the (hopefully very few) packages that you actually need to ask your question (e.g. dplyr). A concise question is easier to understand, and more useful for others in the future. Loading many packages can also lead to confusion as there are often conflicts between packages.